# 403 forbidden on Apache vHost

Tags: permission, apache, mysql, php

I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.8 and I'm trying to configure a vHost. I configured it and it gave me a 403 Forbidden, and I'm having trouble giving _www permission to read/write in ~/Document/workspace/dev

httpd.conf, I thought this might be causing trouble with me accessing public host, not vHost, but I'm not sure.

```
    #
    # ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
    # This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
    # it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
    #
    # If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
    #
    #ServerName www.example.com:80

    #
    # DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
    # documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
    # symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
    #
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
```

I also made sure to uncomment the include on this:

```
    # Virtual hosts
    Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

And I defined these vHosts in httpd-vhosts.conf

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
            DocumentRoot "/Users/isaacbeckett/Documents/workspace/dev"
            ServerName isaac.local
            ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/isaac.local-error_log"
            CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/isaac.local-access_log" common

            <Directory "/Users/isaac/Documents/workspace/dev">
                    AllowOverride All
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

And here is my /etc/hosts file:

```
    ##
    # Host Database
    #
    # localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
    # when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
    ##
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
    ::1             localhost
    fe80::1%lo0     localhost
    127.0.0.1       isaac.local
```

I've flushed the local cache with `dscacheutil -flushcache`
 several times and tried `chmod 755 ~/Documents` as well, but no success. Can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: It's possible that 755 isn't enough if your files/folders are in a different group to httpd and also you've not enabled a file index in the vhost so you'll need to have a file in the folder which is listed in the `DirectoryIndex` parameter otherwise it will show a 403 error as there is no file and and you are forbidden from viewing the file listing. To enable file listings put `Options +Indexes`

Answer (score -1):

This is very much off topic as it is unrelated to Apple hardware/software.  However, I wanted to point you in the right direction.

The problem that you are running into is that

- In your httpd.conf, the directory permissions are not set properly
- Your .htaccess file is not configured properly
- The system doesen't have the correct permissions for the directory

The best thing to do is consult the Apache documentation about the VirtualHost directive.

The Server Fault and/or Super User boards here on Stackexchange would also be beneficial to solving this particular problem.

Comment: Umm, .htaccess? I saw no such file. Also, how can I correct the issue specifically. This isn't very helpful.

Comment: The dot (.) before htaccess indicates it's a hidden file.  It's there...if not in the directory you are trying to browse, in a parent directory possibly all the way up to the "DocumentRoot."  To get specific help, I put that in my answer.

Comment: I know it's hidden, but where is it specifically?

Comment: Google must be broken.  I used Bing and found this for you:  http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-403-forbidden-error-and-solution/

Comment: And Bing also gave this one from Stackoverflow (here) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602331/http-server-error-403-forbidden